# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'dict'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get the error: `while (low <= high) and list[low] <= x <= list[high]:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'dict'`

```
while low <= high and list[low] <= x <= list[high]:
    critical_op += 1
    if low == high:
        if list[low] == x:
            return low
        return -1
```

low = 0 
high = (item - 1)

Comment: what is your low high and list?

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name, shadowing builtins can yield some unsavory results

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback, as well as samples of your inputs

Comment: is the type of list here is `dict`?

Comment: ncica: here is what low and high are.
    low = 0
    high = (item - 1)